# Does there exist such $a_n$ and $b_n$? If not, how do I prove that?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\sum a_n$ be a divergent and $\sum b_n$ be a convergent. I want to find $a_n$ , $b_n$ such that $\sum a_nb_n$ is convergent. Does there exist such $a_n$ and $b_n$? If not, how do I prove that?

Clearly, if both $\sum a_n, \;\;\sum b_n$ are divergent then $\sum a_nb_n$ can be convergent. For example, choose $a_n=b_n=\frac{1}{n}$.

Also, if $\sum a_n, \;\;\sum b_n$ are convergent then $\sum a_nb_n$ can be convergent. For example, choose $a_n=b_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Comment: Why not choose $a_n=1/n$ and $b_n=1/n^2$ then?

Comment: Why not $a_n=1$ and your favourite $b_n$?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you almost find the answer. You consider both $a_{n}=b_{n}=\frac{1}{n}$ and $a_{n}=b_{n}=\frac{1}{n^{2}}$. Maybe you should consider the mixture:) In other words, choose $a_{n}=\frac{1}{n}$ and $b_{n}=\frac{1}{n^{2}}$.